# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException:

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, firefox, scrapy

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: >Element name="Description"> is not reachable by keyboard

I developed the python source code:

```
        # Fill out and submit the new message form
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Title"))).send_keys("Test Title")
        sleep(1)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "SupportId"))).send_keys("بخش مالی (فاکتور/پیش فاکتور/بازگشت وجه)")
        sleep(1)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "DegreeId"))).send_keys("کم")
        sleep(1)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "File"))).send_keys("test.txt")
        sleep(1)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "Description"))).send_keys("Test Message ")
        sleep(1)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="ارسال"]'))).click()
        sleep(1)
```

This python source code is for filling the fields of this form:

```
<div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <p class="modal-title">ارسال پیام جدید</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
<form action="/fa/Account/SendTicket" autocomplete="off" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-complete="onSendTicketComplete" data-ajax-method="POST" id="form2" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="rworgZ7wuRPEkDBjIanQ1WslPXlcnV64qDkPCY2HB-M0WbXYSZjUKcZSEEYChpXPWS2XRi5MGGtu_6CLGIJElF2JTRnCGOMGPg-gCSeZalEpMkPl0">                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <label class="form-label" for="Title">عنوان<span class="label-required">*</span></label>
                            <div class="formElement">
                                <i class="fa fa-font"></i>
                                <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="عنوان را وارد نمایید." id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="">
                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Title" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <label class="form-label" for="SupportId">بخش<span class="label-required">*</span></label>
                            <div class="formElement">
                                <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field بخش must be a number." data-val-required="بخش را وارد نمایید." id="SupportId" name="SupportId"><option value="">-- بخش --</option>
<option value="10164">بخش مالی (فاکتور/پیش فاکتور/بازگشت وجه)</option>
<option value="10163">خدمات پس از فروش (بازکشت کالا)</option>
<option value="10162">پشتیبانی</option>
</select>
                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="SupportId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <label class="form-label" for="DegreeId">اهمیت<span class="label-required">*</span></label>
                            <div class="formElement">
                                <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field اهمیت must be a number." data-val-required="اهمیت را وارد نمایید." id="DegreeId" name="DegreeId"><option value="">-- اهمیت --</option>
<option value="0">کم</option>
<option value="1">متوسط</option>
<option value="2">فوری</option>
<option value="3">بحرانی</option>
</select>
                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DegreeId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <label class="form-label" for="File">فایل</label>
                            <div class="formElement">
                                <i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i>
                                <div>
                                    <label data-target="#mdlSendTicket #File" class="file-button">...</label>
                                    <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control pointer-event-none text-right" dir="ltr" id="File" name="File" type="text" value="">
                                    <span class="file-name"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <label class="form-label" for="Description">متن<span class="label-required">*</span></label>
                            <div class="formElement">
                                <textarea class="form-control" cols="20" data-val="true" data-val-required="متن را وارد نمایید." id="Description" name="Description" rows="5"></textarea>
                                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Description" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button class="animateBtn" type="submit">
                            <i class="fa fa-send"></i>
                            <span>ارسال</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
</form>            </div>
</div>
```

But I get this error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <textarea id="Description" class="form-control maxwidth-100" name="Description"> is not reachable by keyboard
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:183:5
ElementNotInteractableError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:293:5
webdriverSendKeysToElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.sys.mjs:624:13
interaction.sendKeysToElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.sys.mjs:598:11
sendKeysToElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:546:29
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:163:31
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the two options below:

- Using JS's `execute_script`

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('Description').value='Test Message'")
```

- Using `ActionChains` class

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "Description")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).send_keys('Test Message').perform()
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```